# Hiding a layer when clicking anywhere on page except the layer

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('body').click(function() {
//hide layer code here
});
```

This will hide the layer.

But I don't want the layer to be hidden when I click inside/on the layer.

Please help.

Comment: html is a huge page i cant paste it because of privacy issue of the company.
Assume its a big html page , and i want layers to get close when i click anywhere except on the layer

Comment: unless you show your html markup we can;t help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the id to layer. for example: #layer

and put this code to your script file:

```
$('#layer').on('click', function (event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: No prob ;). And I stress that you're right, as of JQuery 1.7 the on() function is the right way to attach events.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it works for the layer and for all its chids. But vote for me also, please :(

Comment: its not working
<div id="layer">
<div id="xyz">
  some content
</div>
</div>

when in click on "xyz" text , will it work ??

Comment: if you want that it not work when you chick on <div id="xyz">, use this: $('#xyz').on('click', function (event) {
event.stopPropagation();
}); 
and write your code for <div id="layer"> normally.

Answer (score 1):

I think the more elegant way is this:

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
// hide layer code here
});
$('#layer').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function(ev){
    if(ev.target.className == 'yourLayerClass') {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: nice , what if my layer design is like
`<div>`
`<div class="a">`
`    <div class="b">`
`    </div>`
`</div>`
`<div class="c">`
`    <div class="d">`
`    </div>`
`</div>`
`</div>`

Comment: add a universal class to all like `layer` or `message` or something beside the `a`, `b`, `c` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
            $('body').click(function(e) {
                if(e.target.id !== 'layer') {
                    alert('Put code to hide layer here');
                }

            });
        });
    </script>


<body>
<p id='layer'>This is layer</p>
<p id='other'>This is other part </p>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/G9FGP/)

Also, you can create an overlay (the standard way)

HTML

```
<body>
<div id='overlay'></div>
<p id='layer'>This is layer</p>
</body>
```

JS

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e) {
    alert('code to hide your layer'); 
    // Notice that this function won run when you click on layer but will run whenever you on any other part of body.
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/Sjje9/1/)

Comment: Not a generalized solution
if layer hot multiple <div> and <p> tags  , it wont work

Comment: added one more solution, the standard way to deal with such situation.  I kept the overlay with Gray background so you can see it. You can keep the `background:white`