# Close Layer on Body and not on click within layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding a layer when clicking anywhere on page except the layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817019/hiding-a-layer-when-clicking-anywhere-on-page-except-the-layer)

I have a layer say code is:

```
<div id=id1">

<div id="id2">

textssssss colorrrrrrrr and other stuff

</div>

textssssss colorrrrrrrr and other stuff

</div>
```

What I want when I click on the layer it continue to be visible and if I click on any other part of body , layer should close.

please help ?

Comment: Show us your jquery code, perhaps in a jsfiddle..

Comment: I checked it , the answer is incorrect as its an not optimal solution
i can't have $('#id').on('click..
$('#id2').on('click .....and so on till all div ids

there has be a better solution

Comment: Also i am using jquery 1.2 and cant change it right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#id1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('#id2').hide();
});
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery 1.2, you should change .on('click') to .bind('click') or even just - .click(callback...)

Comment: I am working on jquery 1.2 so on wont support :-(

If there are 10 ids in my layer, and many divs wid no ids then ??
i need to add ids to all div and need to bind all these ids to make sure layer wont get close on clicking on these ids


sry , but not the solution i am looking for

Comment: As I sad above, you can use bind or click in jQuery 1.2. And you can use classes instead of id's, so you can reach your div via 'classnames' so all you have to change in code i posted - $(this).find('classname') instead of $(this).find('#id2') and all your divs with appropriate classes will be hidden.